# Can't POST using Retrofit on Body raw

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I want to Post data on API using body raw but always got null on response.body and data not send.

Here is my retrofit class:

```
public class ApiClient {
public static Retrofit retrofit;
private static final String BASE_URL = BuildConfig.BASE_URL;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(){
    if (retrofit == null){
        retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    return  retrofit;
}
```

}

then here is the interface:

```
public interface SendData {
@POST("/")
Call<DataItem> sendData(@Body DataItem body);}
```

there is class model:

```
public class DataItem{
private String date;
private String imgUrl;
private double probability;
private String latitude;
private String longtitude;
private String className;

public DataItem(String date, String imgUrl, double probability, String latitude, String longtitude, String className) {
    this.date = date;
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    this.probability = probability;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longtitude = longtitude;
    this.className = className;
}

public String getDate(){
    return date;
}

public String getImgUrl(){
    return imgUrl;
}

public double getProbability(){
    return probability;
}

public String getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public String getLongtitude(){
    return longtitude;
}

public String getClassName(){
    return className;
}
```

}

here is call the retrofit to post data:

```
DataItem data = new DataItem(currentDate, imgUrl, probability, latitude, longitude, class_name);

                    SendData service = ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(SendData.class);
                    Call<DataItem> call = service.sendData(data);
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<DataItem>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<DataItem> call, Response<DataItem> response) {
                            String result = String.valueOf(response.body());
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "response = " + response.message());
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "result = " + result);
                            timingSendData();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Send!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<DataItem> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Send Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

I already used serilaizaton in model also I used hashmap<string,string> but still not able to post data.
API also tested in postman and it's worked

EDIT: after follow @DinkarKumar suggestion, Post data to API is work. but it makes me confused that the response is not on method onResponse() but on method onFailure(), at least data can be Post to API.
PS: I moved the URL of API

Comment: what error code you are getting ?

Comment: @DinkarKumar not error and there is no messsage but data not added in API

Comment: its 200 ok status ?

Comment: @DinkarKumar no it's not , i already checked. status code = 500

Answer (score 1):

You should either change the `className` to `class_name` as that is the real field name, or if you want to stick with `className` then you should annotate `class_name`.
Something like below, the example is using GSON library syntax.

```
@SerializedName("class_name")
public String className;
```

And also your response is not of DataItem it's a String `Image Added` when I tested the same with Postman.

So I think you should also change the

```
Call<DataItem> sendData(@Body DataItem body);
```

to

```
Call<String> sendData(@Body DataItem body);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but saddly still same . status code still 500

Comment: can you post the updated code as I request you to change ,so I can see if everything is fine.

Comment: don't post it as an answer.

Comment: and if you are using GSON SerializedName annotation you need to make all the variable public

Comment: still not work sir. i change only the className to class_name also not work

Comment: status code still 500, i don't know it is the problem of backend or my code. how about my base URL with single path like that

Comment: ThoriqulUmar let me know if you are able to fix it with my and @IndraKumarS suggestions

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the changes recommended by @DinkarKumar, You should have this `Content-Type` header

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@POST("/")
Call<String> sendData(@Body DataItem body);}
```

`API also tested in postman and it's worked` - In Postman also, if you remove the content-type header, You will get HTTP 400 and

```
{
    "msg": "Missing JSON in request"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response is not json object but list. You should change your interface. I think thats why onFailure() triggers.

```
public interface SendData {
@POST
Call<List<DataItem>> sendData(@Body DataItem body);
}
```

Or you just need to wrap that list with json object.

Comment: Hahaha... well confused. And got upvoted also.

Comment: He wants to post a data to the api end point.

Comment: I missunderstood and edited my answer ️